# Sorting a .txt file by column

Tags: linux, sorting

I am trying to learn Linux and I am new to it.

I have a txt file that looks like this:

```
name  second_name   address  phone number
name  second_name   address  phone number
name  second_name   address  phone number
name  second_name   address  phone number
```

I am using a script named telcat and I am reading a variable named N.
I want to sort the file by the Nth column.

Example:

If `N == 2`, I want to sort the file by second_name.
I guess I have to use sort command but I don't understand exactly how.

Thank you.

Comment: No spelling error please.

Comment: Show your effort/code? (edit into the question)

Answer (score 1):

How about:

> sort -k $N file.txt

This will sort file.txt by column number $N

Comment: good, you may add some information about what is `k` and how it works

Comment: Thank you. This is the solution for my problem. ;-)

Comment: ... @Philipp then accept the answer by clicking on the checkmark